# Contract last elements of two lists, if they are zeros in one list

Tags: python

I want:
In:

```
["b","0","0","0"], ["d","e","f","g"]
```

Out:

```
["b","000"], ["d","efg"]
```

My code below is working but I think it really doesn't look very nice and there's probably an easier way to solve this:
In:

```
a=["b","0","0","0"]
c=["d","e","f","g"]

def contractsuffixes(reflex,root):
    laststringreflex=""
    laststringroot=""
    if reflex[-1]=="0":
        for i in reflex[::-1]:
            if i == "0":
                laststringreflex+=reflex[-1]
                laststringroot+=root[-1]
                reflex.pop()
                root.pop()
    elif root[-1]=="0":
        for i in root[::-1]:
            if i == "0":
                laststringreflex+=reflex[-1]
                laststringroot+=root[-1]
                reflex.pop()
                root.pop()
    if laststringreflex != "" and laststringroot != "":
        reflex.append(laststringreflex[::-1])
        root.append(laststringroot[::-1])
    
    return reflex,root
        
contractsuffixes(a,c)
```

Out:

```
(['b', '000'], ['d', 'efg'])
```

Comment: So you want `[a[0], ''.join(a[1:])]`? Why do you have a check that an element is `"0"`? Is that just unnecessary or did I not understand what you are trying to do? How does this relate to "if they are zeros" in the title?

Answer (score 1):

My approach:

- select all trailing zeroes in input list (takeWhile in reversed input)
- count the trailing zeroes from the previous step

If there are no trailing zeroes, there is nothing to concat, return input lists

If there are trailing zeroes:

- split both list in two parts (number of trailing zeroes gives the split point)
- first part is left as is
- second part is joined

```
from itertools import takewhile

a = ["b", "0", "0", "0"]
b = ["d", "e", "f", "g"]

zeroes = list(takewhile(lambda x: x is "0", reversed(a)))

lenZeroes = len(list(zeroes))
a1 = a[:-lenZeroes] + [''.join(zeroes)] if lenZeroes > 0 else a
b1 = b[:-lenZeroes] + [''.join(b[-lenZeroes:])] if lenZeroes > 0 else b
print(a1)
print(b1)
```

Comment: Guess I'll remove mine anyways, looking closely ops solution, it definitely is more involved than that. This one looks much better now +1

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
lists = [["b", "0", "0", "0"], ["d", "e", "f", "g"]]
out_lists = [[lst[0], ''.join(lst[1:])] for lst in lists]

print(out_lists)
```

output

```
[['b', '000'], ['d', 'efg']]
```